# Is there any way to get table metadata using postgREST

Tags: postgresql, postgrest

I need to get table metadata like primary key, column type etc. using PostgRest. By executing the root path `/` of my PostgRest app I am getting  JSON that contains all needed data in `definitions` object.

Unfortunately there is no endpoint to get it and there is no information about that in documentation.

I have tried to execute the following endpoints:
`/table/parameters`
`/table/definitions`
`/table/schema`

All returns `404` error code.

Is there any way to get metadata?

Comment: So... `/` is the endpoint.

Comment: Yes, the `/` is the root endpoint.

Comment: And it contains all the information (metadata) you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write a view or function and call it.  In that SQL return the metadata from anything in your db.